# Frobenius Method For System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a system of ODEs. Can you explain how to solve a system of ODEs using the method Frobenius expansions ?

There are 5 ODEs which are coupled and 5 variables.

$\omega\hat\rho + i\alpha V_z \widehat\rho + i\alpha\rho\widehat {V_z} + \rho\frac{\partial\widehat{V_r}}{\partial r} + in\frac{\rho}{r}\widehat{V_\theta} + \frac{\rho}{r}\widehat{V_r} = 0$

$\omega\widehat{V_r} + i\alpha V_z\widehat{V_r} + \frac{T}{\gamma\rho}\frac{\partial\widehat\rho}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{\gamma}\frac{\partial\widehat T}{\partial r}= 0$

$\omega\widehat{V_\theta} + i\alpha V_z\widehat{V_\theta} + \frac{inT}{\gamma\rho r}\widehat\rho + \frac{in}{\gamma r}\widehat T = 0$

$\omega\widehat{V_z} + \frac{i\alpha T}{\gamma\rho}\widehat\rho + i\alpha V_z\widehat{V_z} + \frac{i\alpha}{\gamma}\widehat T = 0$

$\omega\widehat T + i\alpha(\gamma-1)T\widehat{V_z} + i\alpha V_z\widehat{T} + (\gamma-1)T\frac{\partial\widehat V_r}{\partial r} + (\gamma-1)\frac{T}{r}\widehat{V_r} + in(\gamma-1)\frac{T}{r}\widehat{V_\theta} = 0$

In the above, $\{\widehat{\rho},\widehat{V_r},\widehat{V_\theta},\widehat{V_z},\widehat{T}\}$ are the variables to be solved for in the Frobenius expansion method. $\omega, n, \alpha, \gamma$ are constants.

Comment: Can you post this system?

Comment: $\widehat{T}$ and $\widehat{V}$ look like the kinetic energy and the potential energy operators. Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: Actually the $\widehat{V_r}, \widehat{V_\theta}, \widehat{V_z}$ are velocity modes (complex numbers) in the radial axial and azimuthal directions. $\widehat \rho$ is density mode and $\widehat{T}$ is the temperature mode. The problem arises from the inviscid stability of the Navier-Stokes equations in cylindrical coordinates

Comment: 1- What's the difference between $V_z$ and $\widehat{V}_z$? 2- What is $i$, $i^2=-1$? 3- the third and fourth eqs don't have any derivatives ($\widehat{V}_{\theta}$ doesn't have a derivative). 4- Do you mean $\widehat{T}=\widehat{T}(r,\theta,z)$?

Comment: 1. $V_z$ is the baseflow component. It is a known function of r. $\widehat{V_z}$ is a variable to be solved for. 2. i is sqrt(-1). 3. The coefficient multiplying the derivative of $\widehat{V_\theta}$ (that coefficient is the baseflow radial velocity $V_r$ which is zero in this case). So the derivatives do not appear in those equations. 4. $\widehat{T} = \widehat{T}(r)$ only. Not functions of $\theta$ and $z$. ${\widehat{\rho},\widehat{V_r},\widehat{V_\theta},\widehat{V_z},\widehat{T}$ are functions of $r$ only.

Comment: If you find $\widehat{V}_{\theta}$ and $\widehat{V}_z$ from the third and fourth (algebraic) eqs and substitute them in the other eqs, you'll obtain a system of $3$ ODEs.

Comment: You are right. Actually this system is reducible to 1 ODE which turns out to be a Bessels equation for the pressure mode $\widehat{p}$ (forget the details) which is straightforward to do by the Frobenius method. I am trying to do the Frobenius for the above non reduced  system and get the same result as that obtained from using the single ODE. The reason is that I am going to extend this method to other systems where I have to work with 5 equations and reduction is not possible. Can you tell me how to do for 3 ODEs ? Thanks for your prompt responses.